# Restore Merged Branch in Bitbucket Repo

Tags: git, version-control, merge, bitbucket

Help!  I need to recover a branch.  I've been using `git` with the Bitbucket UI to try and simplify things, but missed a checked checkbox...

**What I did:**

I created a pull request and merged my `feature` branch into the `dev` branch, closing the `feature` branch (desired outcome).

I then created a pull request and merged my `dev` branch into the `staging` branch (desired), but I missed that the checkbox was still marked to "close branch on merge", which happened (not desired).

**What I want:**

I would like to roll back the merge so that I have a `dev` branch with the `feature` branch merged into it (with all its commit history, etc). I don't care if the `staging` branch is `dev`-branch-less, or not, I don't mind creating the pull request and merging them correctly again if necessary. **Is it possible to recover the dev branch with its history now that it has been closed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to recover the `dev` branch with its history now that it has been closed?

If you still have the branch locally - simply use it, push the local branches to the remote and merge the feature branch into it if you need to.

---

## In case you don't have any of those branches.

#### What to do?

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716) answer and learn how to use reflog to recover your branches.
[[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716])

Another option is to checkout the merged branch and to split it into the desired commits using the `checkout` command - again full details in the above answer.

Another option is to checkout the base branch and use cherry-pick to select the range of commits you need.

Comment: Thank you @codeWizard! I was able to use `git reset` referenced above to bring my local `dev` branch up to date, and then pushed it to the repo, which restored all the back references to previous commits as well.

Comment: Cool, if the second answer helped you out please be kind enough to vote for it as well. im spending a lot of time writing good and detailed answer so  users can solve thier problems and learn new materials as well. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is push the `dev` branch from local machine and it will create a new `origin/dev` branch on BitBucket. No need to create a new pull request.

Comment: Will this restore the commit history the dev branch previously had? @tejasbubane

Comment: It will unless you changed something on the `dev` branch on local, which I assume you have not.