# How do "reuse" a branch on Bitbucket / Sourcetree after merge

Tags: version-control, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I was working on a branch of my Bitbucket repo (lets call it "frontend-dev"), which has now been merged with the master branch. I would like to branch again to make further changes, without creating a new branch. How do I branch and get back onto "frontend-dev".

I am using Sourcetree to manage version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally merging to master does not close or delete the branch. If there are changes in master since the merge from "frontend-dev", you can merge back to "frontend-dev". Either way, you can then simply switch your working copy to "frontend-dev" and continue developing.

Another question discusses what to do when you have closed or deleted the branch: [Restore Merged Branch in Bitbucket Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490166/restore-merged-branch-in-bitbucket-repo)

Comment: In case any other noobs come across this, the steps are 1) ensure that you have pulled changes from the master branch 2) checkout the older branch you wish to continue working 3) select the latest commit of the master branch again 4) "merge" and select merge into current branch (the older branch you checked out) - this puts you back on your old branch ready to commit more changes.